# Mongoose - findOneAndUpdate not populating _id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

It seems that anywhere I do a `findOneAndUpdate` call that my item gets saved, but the `_id` field is not set.

The options I am using to insert into my empty collection are:

```
{
  upsert: true,
  setDefaultsOnInsert: true,
  strict: false,
  new: true,
  runValidators: true
}
```

Running on mongoose 4.11.  When I turn the debug on in mongoose, I do not see `_id` in the `$setOnInsert`, or `$set` objects.  am I missing something?  I get the document back in the callback but `_id` is `null`.  Noting in my super simple schema controls `_id`

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post what your query and data for the findOneAndUpdate command are?